# Adaptive card media element not showing video

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards

I am making chatbot application where i need to play video on chat window so for that i used adaptive card and media element inside it. i copied json from https://adaptivecards.io/designer and made card of it and send as attachment of messageactivity to the client.below is my code 
Json Code

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Media",
            "poster": "https://adaptivecards.io/content/poster-video.png",
            "sources": [
                {
                    "mimeType": "video/mp4",
                    "url": "https://adaptivecardsblob.blob.core.windows.net/assets/AdaptiveCardsOverviewVideo.mp4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.1",
    "fallbackText": "This card requires Media to be viewed. Ask your platform to update to Adaptive Cards v1.1 for this and more!"
}
```

and in the c# i have used it like this

```
string json = "{  '$schema': 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',  'type': 'AdaptiveCard',  'version': '1.1',  'fallbackText': 'This card requires Media to be viewed. Ask your platform to update to Adaptive Cards v1.1 for this and more!',    'body': [        {            'type': 'Media',            'poster': 'https://adaptivecards.io/content/poster-video.png',            'sources': [                {                    'mimeType': 'video/mp4',                    'url': 'https://adaptivecardsblob.blob.core.windows.net/assets/AdaptiveCardsOverviewVideo.mp4'                }            ]        }    ]}";
AdaptiveCard adaptiveCards = new AdaptiveCard();
adaptiveCards = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(json).Card;

IMessageActivity messageActivity = context.MakeMessage();
var Attach = new Attachment()
{
    ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
    Content = adaptiveCards

};
messageActivity.Attachments.Add(Attach);
List<CardAction> lstCard = GetSuggestedActions();

messageActivity.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
{
    Actions = lstCard
};
await context.PostAsync(messageActivity);
```

But it shows nothing when i test it on both bot emulator and after deployed.
one thing i noticed on bot emulatot it gives me error

**[err-client] Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null C:\Users\amit.yadav\AppData\Local\botframework\app-3.5.29\resources\app\node_modules\rxjs\Subscriber.js 227 13 {} **
and output looks like below

[image]

please help me where i am doing wrong thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to the latest version of Emulator: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/releases/tag/v4.4.1

While Web Chat does currently seem to have issues displaying media in Adaptive Cards, you can try video cards in the meantime if that will help unblock you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.videocard

Comment: Thanks @kyle delaney in the new bot emulator it is working but in the production after deploying the bot framework as attached it to Microsoft bot and the same problem occured does not show anything just empty adaptive card.

Comment: Most channels don't support Adaptive Cards. What channel are you using?

Comment: i am using webchat.

Comment: I've logged a bug in the Web Chat repo for you: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/2060

Comment: While that's being investigated, I would appreciate it if you would upvote and accept my answer and follow the GitHub issue for any future updates